# React-router-dom link page not working correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom library for work with routers, but when I want to link to another page it dosen't change the page and added new page right after previous change like bellow image.
How can I fix this? [mentioned image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbkdT.png)

Main.js:

```
const routes = (
<HashRouter>
  <div>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
  </div>
</HashRouter>
);

ReactDom.render(routes , document.getElementById('app'));
```

Link page:

```
<Menu.Item key="morepage:about"><Link to="/about">About Page</Link></Menu.Item>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make use of `<Switch>` and put `path="/"` on the last

```
import {HashRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
<HashRouter>
    <div>
        <Switch>
                <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                <Route path="/" component={App} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
</HashRouter>
```

Comment: thank you it works. also no need to second div tag inside the Switch tag.

Comment: and i have a question: why i have to put path="/" at the last? is there a certion reason for this?

Comment: we need to put path="/" to avoid ambiguity with other paths